# Wifi 802.11n speed with router (TD-W8968) only 1MB/s?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, speed

Reading about theoretical and real world limits of Wifi 802.11n I should get way more than about 1MB/s speed out of my router. But I can't. And I wonder why.

As standard I have 5 devices at home - Acer laptop, Samsung phone, MacBook, Iphone and Brother printer. None of them ever get more than approx 1MB/s from local or internet connection.

My last test was:

1. switch off everything except of Acer laptop with Qualcomm Atheros AR5b97 network adapter with the 2016 driver version 10.0.0.336. and putting it right next to router
2. plug in HDD drive into routers (tp-link TD-W8968) USB 2.0 port. (When connected directly to laptop through USB 2.0 I get about 30 MB/s constant reading speed)
3. make sure wifi connection is enabled and set to mode 11n only, channel auto and channel width 40MHz

And again I did get only like 1MB/s reading speed. One thing in my mind is there is a lot of Wifi networks in the area, only few with strong signal but in total about 15 signals.

**Any help how to increase my speed to expected at least 10MB/s or explanation why is it only 1MB/s appreciated.**

Comment: @Ramhound thank you for pointing that out, it indeed sounds similar and as duplicate, I am going to test the answers from suggested question and probably delete my or completely rephrase it, especially if any of the answers of similar question works for me.

Comment: Using a 40MHz channel width in a congested area sounds like a really terrible idea. Also, routers make terrible file servers. What speed do you get if you connect using wired Ethernet to the router?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thank you, I had no idea it can be that terribly bad. Connected through wired directly into router I get only slightly better speed like 1.8 MB/s of reading from usb HDD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routers make *really* terrible file servers. Either use a proper NAS device or try using third party firmware. It's not a WiFi issue. Return your WiFi settings to defaults and don't use a 40Mhz channel width.